# Checking document count in PyMongo.cursor.Cursor inside if statement in python behaving wierdly

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have the following python code:

```
placeholder = db.user.aggregate(...)

if len(list(placeholder))!=0:
     #execute something
```

Now the issue is even if the mongo cursor doesn't have any documents, it still getting inside the if statement.
But if I am modifying the code as:

```
placeholder = list(db.user.aggregate(...))

if len(placeholder)!=0:
     #execute something
```

its working normally.
even if pymongo cursor object is an iterator and it can be exhausted but the only thing I am doing is checking the length and converting it into a list. Can anyone please advice why its behaving this way in the first case.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the query is the same, the two statements are identical.

In the first query - how do you *know* there's no records. You exhaust the cursor without saving any results to look at. Also how is it possible that "the mongo cursor doesn't have any documents", while `len(list(cursor))` returns a non-zero value.

If you are really stuck, post a [Minimal Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks. I think thats what I was doing wrong. By doing list(cursor) i was exhausting the cursor.